# Download SSRS report from Server to my desktop

Tags: reporting-services, download, report

It's been a while since I last did this. I want to download a SSRS report on the server so I can bring it into the designer and see what it is doing. I went to the server (screenshot below), but not sure where to find the download option. I clicked around but can't find anything. I see that if I hover over a report (circled), a down arrow appears but that seems to do nothing.

[image]

**How can I download a report to my computer?**

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this old version is a while, but I believe you need to go to the report properties and then use the Download button on the menu bar.

[image]

Comment: I know I did something like that before, but not sure why I can't get to a screen that shows that. Can you show me (1) what the link is (perhaps a general format of it if you don't want to show me the specific link, and (2) what the screen looks like below what you showed.

Comment: @AndrewYi - I haven't had that old version for a few years but I think you use the drop down circled in your pic and choose Properties or Manage to get to the screen in my pic. If you open the report, there should be a link to go the Properties, too.